# Ruby creating a new hash from an array of key, value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, each

```
first_response = [
  {"xId" => "123", "yId" => "321"}, 
  {"xId" => "x",   "yId" => "y"  }
]

first_response.each do |resp|
  x_id = resp['xId']
  y_id = resp['yId']
  puts x_id.to_s
  puts y_id.to_s
end
```

This gives me outputs

```
123
321
x
y
```

output hash I want to create is
`{123=>{321}, x=>{y}}`

first service: I have an array of hash that has two different ids example:(x_id and y_id) (there would be multiple pairs like that in the response)

I want to create a hash that should contain the matching pair of x_id and y_ids that we get from the first service with x_id's as the key for all the pairs.

Comment: Do you have examples of the input and expected output, and what you've tried?

Comment: `Hash[[[:a, 1], [:b, 2], [:c, 3]]]` gives `=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3} `

Comment: {
  "first_service": [
    {
      
      "x": "string",
   "y": "string",
      "other": {
        "a": "string",
        "b": "string",
        "c": "string"
      },
      "other-2": {
        "l": "CONFIRMED",
        "m": "2021-12-03T15:10:21.330Z",
        "n": "2021-12-03T15:10:21.330Z"
      }
    }
  ]
}

I want to group this as 

hash_ =
  {
    "x": {
      'y': "y",
    }
  }

Comment: I can iterate through the first service and get the x and y separately in their own array by iterating through the first service one by one like belowfor both (x and y seperately),  but not able to group them.
# x = [].tap do |ids|
      #   first.each do |element|
      #     x = element['x']
      #     ids.push(x) unless x.nil? || ids.include?(x)
      #   end
      # end

Answer (score 2):

If you know every hash in `first_response` is going to contain exactly two key/value pairs, you can extract their values and then convert that result into a hash (see [`Enumerable#to_h`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_h)):

```
first_response.to_h(&:values)
# {"123"=>"321", "x"=>"y"}
```

Comment: so using the above approach that I shared I can get the output but I think I need to add another key inside of the first one and get the output like {"123"=>{"abc" =>321"}, "x"=>{"xyz"=>"y"}}, how can achieve that

Comment: Can you update your question? I don't get how you come up with those `abc`/`xyz` keys there @Dev.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this approach works, but I am not completely sure if that is right

```
first_response = [{"xId"=>"123","yId"=> "321"}, {"xId"=>"x","yId"=> "y"}]                         
h = {}.tap do |element|
  first_response.each do |resp|
    x_id = resp['xId']
    y_id = resp['yId']
    element[x_id] = y_id
  end
end
puts h.to_s
# {"123"=>"321", "x"=>"y"}
```